# Pivot a table in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to pivote a table in reporting services 2008? If so, how?
I'd like to pivote it 90 degrees.

Thanks

Comment: Rotate as in pivot it ?? Or rotate as in physically rotate the whole table ??

Comment: As in having the Columns to the left and the rows lined out to the right where the columns usually are.

Comment: I edited this question in order to be specific for pivote and not rotating, I came here looking for how to rotate it, not pivote it. Good question and answer (voted it up) but not related.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In SSRS 2008, there isn't much difference between rows and columns.* A Table is an instance of a "Tablix" which has the detail group on the rows. You can have your table either repeat rows or columns based on the groupings and where the details group is set.

You can create a horizontally expanding table by:

1. First create a Tablix by dragging the Matrix Report Item onto the design surface. The Tablix will have a RowGroup and a ColumnGroup by default.
2. Delete the Row Group by right clicking on it and selecting "Delete Group" In the Delete Group prompt, delete just the group (Not related rows and columns; you'll probably want these as left label for your rows.)
3. Add the Details group as a Child Group of the Column Group. Do this by Right clicking on the Column Group and "Add Group->Child Group..." Select Show Details Data.

The resulting tablix should look something like this:

[image: Horizontally expanding Tablix]

You can now add columns, rows, groups, etc.

*One minor difference that comes to mind is that you can merge cells horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: how to continue from here? to add columns on the side