# SSRS - Column Group - Table Horizontally Expanded

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

There was a requirement, to have data horizontally expanded in the Rows. So I have created Child Row group in Column group of Matrix as shown in this link.

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002796/rotate-a-table-in-reporting-services)

It is working fine. And it displays result as below.

[image]

Requirement was : Show Thumbnails of images uploaded for a building as above.

But now the problem is, when there will be number of images, this is going to be expanded horizontally.

I want to repeat this Row after 8 or 10 images.

Any Idea how can I achieve this in SSRS ?

Thank you,

Mittal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure about your requirement, do you want those images wrap in your report, each row has maximum 8 images? If so, we need to make each 8 images into one group. In this scenario, we can create a list. If you have a index field (like a specific id for each image) in your dataset, we can put in the group expression with this:

=ceiling(Fields!Index.Value/8)

If you don't have this kind of index column, we can make it manually. Embed the custom code below:

```
Dim CountNumber As Integer = 0
Public Shared Previous as Object
Public Function GroupNumber(ByVal category As Object) As Integer
If Category <> Previous then
    CountNumber = CountNumber + 1
    Return CountNumber
Else    
    Return CountNumber
End If
End Function
```

Then replace the group expression with this:

=ceiling(Code.GroupNumber(Fields!Image.Value)/8)

I have tested in my local environment and it works. But I can't share the screenshot due to low reputation.