# How to convert Horizontal table to vertical table in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have to show all my headers left side vertically and values right to it instead of horizontal display?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate a table in reporting services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002796/rotate-a-table-in-reporting-services)

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

1. Add a matrix
2. Delete RowsGroup
3. In columns groups set the value fields you want to put vertically

You'll get something like this:

[image]

4. Manually input headers

This is the preview:

[image]

Let me know if this could help you.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me 1.5 years later :)