# How to show row to column in SSRS report?

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have one dataset name called ds_GetListOfOperations.

That dataset i have two fields ID and Operations.

**E.g:**

```
Id   Operations
----------------
1       OP10
2       OP20
3       OP30
```

In SSRS I would like to show Operations in Row to Column wise. How to do that.

**E.g : Output**

```
OP10   OP20  OP30
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate a table in reporting services?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002796/rotate-a-table-in-reporting-services)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a duplicate question. Please see the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002796/rotate-a-table-in-reporting-services

Alternatively you can also use the pivot function within your SQL before utilizing the query within SSRS.

Comment: Hey, @a415! Thank you for noticing that this question is a duplicate. It would be better to note that in a comment under the question. (If you had above 15 reputation on this site, it would be even better to flag this question, and select duplicate as the reason.)

 As for your answer itself, if you just expanded the last sentence, it would be great!

Comment: In fact, I'll flag the question as a duplicate, while I'm here! :)

Comment: @Numeri Yeah I intended to do that, but I couldn't flag it unfortunately, due to my reputation.

Comment: OK. I've flagged it now, in any case, but it would still be great to improve your answer; it seems to be useful to me!