# Add color and format data in table header and body only in excel export SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In my SSRS report body I have added a table with header. I need help in 2 tasks here please.

1. I need to add background color to the header of table only while exporting it to excel.(Not while viewing it on web/exporting to PDF)
2. If the table data repeats then I need to change rows to columns.
   Example: 
   Name     Age     Details 
   Test     24      Working 
   Test     24      Married 
   Test1    28      Working

I need above data to be the same while exporting it to pdf and viewing on web but it should change as below while exporting to excel.

Name     Age     Detail1   Details2 
Test     24      Working    Married 
Test1    28      Working

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two tables, one with what you want in excel and one with what you want otherwise. Then use `Globals!RenderFormat` to determine the hidden property of those two tables? Example [here](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/).

Comment: thank you for response Tim. Using render format based on your idea now i can add background color to header. So now point 1 is cleared. Instead of adding second table is it possible to change rows to columns depending on data so that we don't have to design two tables just for excel

Comment: Couldn't you also have the excel-version table with a different layout as per point 2?

Comment: I didn't get it?? i am trying to find a way to convert rows to columns based on data in column1 so that single table can be used. Please let me know if you have a way to do it.

Comment: So for your excel version tablix just follow answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002796/rotate-a-table-in-reporting-services). That way the excel one will have the correct colour headers and be laid-out a different way if you choose that render.

Comment: Please review my requirement once. I don't want to turn whole table. Just a part of it and only while exporting to excel.