# SSRS - Convert multiple rows into multiple columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, fetchxml

I have a fetchxml data set and design as per below in my ssrs.

[image]

My preview was like this.

[image]

What I want to achieve is, supposed to be like this.

```
Parentaccountid    StatusH1    StatusH2
Parent Account A    Final       Draft
Parent Account B    Draft       Final
```

So, what I did is adding Row Parent group and group by Parentaccountid, but what I get is only first row for each Parent Account A and Parent Account B.

Comment: You need to add a column group, Take a look at this very similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007678/400375

Comment: Thanks Jamie, but I dont really understand your answer explanation.